# How to login a user using an email provider from the backend in Next.js with NextAuth?

Tags: next.js, next-auth

I am building a Next.js application that uses NextAuth for authentication. On my landing page, I have an email input form that users can fill out and submit. When the user submits their email, they are redirected to a createOrSignIn page, and the email is added as a parameter to the URL.

On the createOrSignIn page, I have implemented a reCAPTCHA that verifies whether the user is a human. After the user is redirected, I extract the email from the URL and validate it. Then, I need to make an API request to my backend Next.js API to verify the reCAPTCHA token and sign in the user using email provider.

However, I am having trouble finding a solution to log in the user using the email provider from the backend.

Can anyone provide guidance on how to sign in a user using the email provider from the backend with NextAuth in Next.js?

Thank you in advance for any help you can provide!

I have tried several approaches to log in the user using the email provider from the backend with NextAuth in Next.js

What I expected to happen was to be able to log in the user using the email provider from the backend with NextAuth in Next.js without requiring the user to be redirected.

The flow I expect is as follows:

1. User fills out and submits the email input form on the landing page.
2. User is redirected to the createOrSignIn page, and the email is added as a parameter to the URL.
3. ReCAPTCHA v3 is displayed on the createOrSignIn page.
4. After validate email, a request is sent to the backend API to verify the reCAPTCHA token.
5. If the reCAPTCHA token is verified, the user is signed in using the NextAuth email provider, and a response is returned to indicate whether a verification email was sent to the user and whether the user exists or is new.
6. If the user is new, a new user form is displayed where the user can fill out their username.